# Is there a word for "property manager" that also includes landlords?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

I'm trying to communicate something along the lines of:

> Your property manager or landlord should be available in the event of an emergency.

I'd like to make "property manager or landlord" more concise.  Property manager works well for condos that are owned by a company; landlord works well for properties that are individually owned; but I don't know what word to use that clearly applies to both.

Comment: I'm lost as to why *property manager* doesn't include landlords. It is implied that through their ownership and their leasing it to an individual they become the manager for that property in addition to simply owning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are drawing a fine distinction between the two words (often they are one and the same) you could use:

> *A representative of your building* should be available in the event of an emergency.

Note that a *representative* can be even broader than either *property manager* or *landlord*. It could be, for instance, a lawyer or assistant who is authorized to speak on behalf of the owner or manager.